# Why don't any of my buttons work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

First i had the sqrt button which worked fine, and then I added the pi button, and nothing worked, i tried changing everything and i still don't know whats wrong! Please someone help.

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
from math import *

def sqrt_():
    text = ment.get()
    a = sqrt(text)
    label['text'] = a

def pi_():
    text = ment.get()
    a = pi(text)
    label_1['text'] = a

root = Tk()
root.title('Conversions')
root.geometry('400x400')

#Get square root
sqrt_button = Button(root, text='Get Square root',command= sqrt_).place(x='160', y='5')
label = Label(root, text='')
label.place(x=5, y=30)
ment = IntVar()
entry = Entry(textvariable=ment).place(x='5', y= '10 ')
#Get Pi
pi_button = Button(root, text='Get Pi',command= pi_).place(x='160', y='50')
label_1 = Label(root, text='')
label_1.place(x=55, y=200)
ment = IntVar()
entry_1 = Entry(textvariable=ment).place(x='5', y= '55 ')


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't define the function `pi` which means when you click the second button it will fail.

Second, you redefined the `ment`. In this case both two entries will be bound to the same int. This means when you click the first button, it will read the value from the second entry. So change all the second `ment` to `ment_1`. The name, the name in entry and the name in `pi_`.

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
from math import *

def sqrt_():
    text = ment.get()
    a = sqrt(text)
    label['text'] = a

def pi_():
    label_1['text'] = pi

root = Tk()
root.title('Conversions')
root.geometry('400x400')

#Get square root
sqrt_button = Button(root, text='Get Square root',command= sqrt_).place(x='160', y='5')
label = Label(root, text='')
label.place(x=5, y=30)
ment = IntVar()
entry = Entry(textvariable=ment).place(x='5', y= '10 ')
#Get Pi
pi_button = Button(root, text='Get Pi',command= pi_).place(x='160', y='50')
label_1 = Label(root, text='')
label_1.place(x=55, y=200)
ment_1 = IntVar()
entry_1 = Entry(textvariable=ment_1).place(x='5', y= '55 ')


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Updated. Please check. Just several small changes. `pi` is removed for undefined. You should define it first and then add it.

Answer (score 0):

pi isn't a function it is a constant so:

```
def pi_():
    label_1['text'] = pi
```